# Is the “missing Unicode character” box a Unicode character itself, and if so, which one?

Tags: html, unicode, windows-xp

When browsing the web in Windows XP, Windows is often unable to render more esoteric unicode characters. When this occurs, it replaces the characters with a small box.

If you’re running Windows XP, the following should render as this box, for example: ︙

Is this box a Unicode character itself?

If so, I was thinking that I could put it in my web pages, and see if other Unicode characters I was attempting to use were the same width as it, in order to check whether the other characters were supported or not.

Comment: At least in my computer/browser, the displayed character is not always the same... It's a box with the hexadecimal code point inside.

Comment: @Álvaro: aha! Yes, I’ve seen that too. Hm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect browser character support in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635683/detect-browser-character-support-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Unicode code point. It may represent a single character or be one of the combining points (multiple code points forming a character)

Comment: Alrighty. Does that mean I can actually use it in a web page?

Comment: To detect whether a font supports the character? Apparently yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635683/detect-browser-character-support-in-javascript

Comment: WINNER, that’s the stuff. Bravo!