# Show some text if missing emoji in HTML

Tags: html

Is there a way in HTML or Angular to show some text if an emoji is missing? For instance, the thinking face emoji is missing in Windows 8, so I was hoping to show some alternative text if possible.

The emoji code is 🤔

My HTML is simple:

```
<div ng-switch-when="folder"
     ng-bind-html="Some text &#x1f914;">
</div>
```

Comment: HTML or Angular?

Comment: Updated question - any solution will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect browser character support in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635683/detect-browser-character-support-in-javascript)

Comment: Hey AshD, ever found a solution?

Comment: Hello  domdom - Unfortunately, I do not have a solution. We just decided to remove the emoji for now!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/) to import a font that you *know* contains the required unicode characters. Then, you can either use that font for all of the affected paragraphs, or just for the "emojis" by using the [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) descriptor.

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Someemojifont';
  src: url('some-emoji-font.otf');
  unicode-range: U+1F914; /* thinking face */
}
```

I understand that this isn't an exact answer to the question at hand, but it might still be a valid solution to the problem that motivated the question.