# Is it safe to assume users can see unicode characters U+2716 and U+2714 in CSS content?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I'm wanting to use the characters ✖ (U+2716) and ✔ (U+2714) in my CSS for form validation purposes. Basically, if a field is valid/invalid, I use the after pseudo class to insert the corresponding symbol after the field.

For example:

```
.field:after {
  content: "\2716";
}
```

This is working great on my Mac, but when I switch to my Windows XP VMWare instance, I don't get the characters, no matter what font I choose (even Arial).

My suspicion is that perhaps my Windows VM isn't configured properly, but that causes me to be weary of using these characters at all.

Does anyone know if there are "safe" characters or ranges in unicode that you can reliably assume will be viewable by most people?

**UDPATE:**

Here is a list of unicode characters I was hoping to possibly be able to use as icons. Specifically the dingbats section.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Dingbats

If you don't see these characters on your machine, definitely let me know in the comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which of the following Unicode characters should be used in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702447/which-of-the-following-unicode-characters-should-be-used-in-html) (assuming that the main question here is about the safe ranges. If its about specific chars, possible duplicate of other things such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635683/detect-browser-character-support-in-javascript?lq=1).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to the problems of using CSS for presenting essential information (see [CSS Caveats](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css-caveats.html)), there’s the problem that the characters mentioned are often not available in people’s computers. The [fonts supporting them](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2716/fontsupport.htm) do not contain any font that is shipped with a Windows system, for example. Support exists in Arial Unicode MS, which is shipped with Microsoft Office, but not everyone is using Office.

Besides, the symbols are not universal. A symbol like “✔” meant *wrong* when I was at school.

Using “OK” and “error” might be best, unless you need to use some other language.

Comment: ...that, or graphical symbols in `background-image`s. They bring their own problems, but they're definitely safer than Unicode characters

Comment: @Jukka that fileformat.info link is **very** helpful, thank you.

Comment: Also, good point about the checkbox. I'm using the icons primarily as yet another visual cue, but I'll probably stick to only using the "X" icon for the error case. Most forms just use red text and a red outline, but that isn't helpful for people who are colorblind.

Comment: www.fileformat.info is down for some time now. The link doesn’t work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using in your XP VM?  IE6 and 7 don't support the `:after` selector, so that might be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I know IE6 and IE7 don't support pseudo classes. I'm using IE8. I can see certain characters, just not those, so I know it's a font issue.